# Remote views and non-basic operations

Tags: java, android, android-widget, view

I'm starting with Android widgets and I'd like to know how to make "complex" calls for the widget view's, for example apply a matrix transformation to an ImageView.

Is possible to do that? Should I use RemoteViews class? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm starting with Android widgets

I am assuming here that you mean "app widgets".

> and I'd like to know how to make "complex" calls for the widget view's, for example apply a matrix transformation to an ImageView

That is not supported, sorry. Because the actual app widget's `View`s are in another application (in that application's own process), you have a very limited API for working with them, in the form of a `RemoteViews` data structure. That does not support arbitrary operations, particularly involving complex parameters.